# blank page nginx and php7.3

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

My server is Nginx. My site is made on Codeigniter

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name idealcloud.idealcontrol.cl;

    root /var/www/idealcontrol_cloud/idealcloud/idealcloud_ox_cer/sys/;
    index index.php home.php login.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }

}
```

but it shows only blank page, no error in nginx log and codeigniter log.. do anyone know this?

Answer (score 0):

sadly, codeigniter doesn't work as seamlessly with Nginx as it does with Apache, so you need quite a bit more configuration on your `nginx.conf` file in order to get a properly functioning Codeigniter site.

I don't remember the exact minimum configuration, so I'll give you some excerpts of the one I'm working on right now. Replace domains, paths and users for your own

Nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 65535;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {
         charset utf-8;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        server_tokens off;
        log_not_found off;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        client_max_body_size 16M;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

        # MIME
        include mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        # logging
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

        # load configs
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;

                server_name example.com;
                set $base /home/path/to/wwwdir;
                root $base;

                # this is important so that nginx and CI can work together without htaccess    
                # index.php
                index index.php;

                # index.php fallback
                location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                }

                # this is important so that nginx and CI can work together without htaccess
                # handle .php
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;

                        # fastcgi
                        fastcgi_pass                            unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index                           index.php;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        fastcgi_param                           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param                           PHP_ADMIN_VALUE open_basedir=$base/:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp/;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;

                        fastcgi_buffer_size                             128k;
                        fastcgi_buffers                                 256 16k;
                        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size               256k;
                        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
                        # fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

                        # default fastcgi_params
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }

                # security headers
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;

                 # . files
                location ~ /\. {
                        deny all;
                }

                # assets, media
                location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
                        expires 7d;
                        access_log off;
                }

                # svg, fonts
                location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
                        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
                        expires 7d;
                        access_log off;
                }

                # gzip
                gzip on;
                gzip_vary on;
                gzip_proxied any;
                gzip_comp_level 6;
                gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
        }

                # subdomains redirect
        server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;

                server_name *.example.com;

                return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
        }
}
```

The above is by no means complete (lacks the HTTPS configuration and some other stuff) but should be enough to get you started